# How to create Map from Vector

Tags: haskell, vector, hashmap

The containers package already contains functions to convert Set and List to  Map but it's missing one for Vector from vector package.

Is this because package developers do not want to have dependencies on other (similar) packages?

Shouldn't be some general package which converts between data structures? In this way I always have to convert to List to convert to other structures. But I want to minimize use because of performance.

Comment: I don't think you should be worried about the overhead of an intermediate list – `Map` contains the same kind of indirections, you'll never get as good bandwidth as `vector` would manage. Unless you're starting out with a sorted array, map construction is anyways _O_ (_n_ · log _n_), so the list overhead is in fact amortised! — You can however quite easily check it by directly folding `insert` over a vector. I don't reckon it'll give better performance than converting to and from list.

Comment: The intermediate list should be either deforested or garbage-collected in a "streaming" fashion, using O(1) memory. So, it's not a big problem. But if you strongly want to avoid that, we have `Foldable Vector` so we could use `foldr` over the `Vector` and insert each element in a `Map`. This might be slower or faster -- try both and see which approach is the fastest.

Comment: @leftaroundabout So if I understand you correctly, using Map is so slow so it does matter to convert to intermediate structure anymore? But converting directly from Vector to Map instead of Vector to List, then List to Map should be faster says my common sense :-)

Comment: @Rik: yeah, but the tradeoff is likely something like: eliminating the list gives you 0.1% better performance in some specific program, but including `vector` as an extra dependency for `containers` and writing an optimised list-free construction function would prolong the build times of some projects by perhaps 20%. — If you're so concerned with micro-optimisation, you should probably not use `Map` at all but e.g. ordered unboxed vectors.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I already use Vector package because Hasql package. I want to add containers package for Map. The point is that I do not want to convert to List everytime. Not only because of performance but also because it feels like boilerplate code. Good idea, I can try to code without Map and stay with Vector.

Comment: Boilerplate? Just define `fromVector = fromList . toList :: Vector (a,b) -> Map a b` somewhere in your module... — As for performance: always remember the [root of all evil](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks! Yeah, I'm aware of the `root of all evil` :-)