# Lookup values inside a Cassava-ingested CSV

Tags: haskell

I successfully read in a CSV using Cassava (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava) with this:

```
getData = do
  csvData <- BL.readFile "data.csv"
  case decodeByName csvData of
    Left err -> putStrLn err
    Right (_, v) -> V.forM_ v $ \ p ->
      putStrLn $ col1 p ++ "," ++ col2 p ++ "," ++ (show $ col3 p) ++ "," ++ (show $ col4 p) ++ "," ++ (show $ col5 p) ++ "," ++ col6 p ++ "," ++ (show $ col7 p) ++ "," ++ (show $ col8 p) ++ "," ++ (show $ col9 p) ++ "," ++ (show $ col10 p)
```

What I actually need to do is use the values in `col3` as keys to find values in `col10`.

Someone suggested that I use `Map` from Data.Map (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html) for this, but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Everything I have tried so far has not worked.  I assume you enter the `Map` inside the `Right` case, along the lines of:

```
    Right (_, v) -> Map (V.forM_ v) ???
```

But I am stuck on how to proceed.  Would appreciate any suggestions.  Ideally, I would want to modify `getData` so that it is `getData keyToFetch = ...` -- and that `keyToFetch` would be used in the `Map`.

Comment: Why are you assuming that you enter the Map inside Right? On what is that assumption based?

Comment: My thought was that that was where the non-error outputs live.  I know it's wrong, it was just my best guess on how to proceed.

Comment: what does col1 col2 etc refer to? They are not defined?

Comment: They are both `Int`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is probably a good idea to use Data.Map to find values in *col10* using values in *col3* as keys.

As we have little data about col3, col10 and the exact data type you are using, I will resort to adapting the [*decodebyName* example in the Cassava documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava) to the idea of generating a map object. The example is based on a very simple {name, salary} type of record.

The two branches of the *case of* construct have to return a common type, in our case a Data.Map object instead of an `IO ()` action. Fortunately, the `error` function is flexible enough that it can pretend to be of the appropriate type.

This would give this sort of code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Data.Csv
import qualified Data.Vector as  V
import qualified Data.Map    as  M
import Control.Monad  (forM_)


data Person = Person
    { name   :: !String
    , salary :: !Int
    } deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)  -- need that for Map objects

instance FromNamedRecord Person where
    parseNamedRecord r = Person <$> r .: "name" <*> r .: "salary"


-- build a map object:
makeMap :: V.Vector Name -> V.Vector Person -> M.Map String Int
makeMap hdr pvec =
    -- with name and salary playing the role of col3 and col10:
    let pls = V.toList pvec  -- get a list
        zls = zip  (map name pls)  (map salary pls)
    in  M.fromList zls


showRecord :: String -> Int -> String
showRecord  name salary  =  name ++ " earns " ++ (show salary) ++ " dollars"


main :: IO ()
main = do
    csvData <- BL.readFile "salaries.csv"
    let ma = case decodeByName csvData of
               Left errMsg       -> error $ "decodeByName failed: " ++ errMsg
               Right (hdr, pvec) -> makeMap hdr pvec
    -- print out the Map object:
    putStrLn  $  "Contents of map object:"
    putStrLn  $  show ma
    putStrLn  $  ""
    forM_  (M.toList ma)  (\(n,s) -> putStrLn $ showRecord n s) 
    let  sal1 = M.lookup  "John Doe"  ma
    putStrLn  $  "sal1 = " ++ (show sal1) 
    --
```

- **Execution:**

```
Contents of map object:
fromList [("Jane Doe",60000),("John Doe",50000)]

Jane Doe earns 60000 dollars
John Doe earns 50000 dollars
sal1 = Just 50000
```

Note that I have to use plain lists extensively, as for some reason there is no direct route from vectors to maps, something discussed already in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960585/how-to-create-map-from-vector).